# Derivation of intial bearing calculation

Tags: gis, bearing

I needed to make calculations of the initial bearing between two coordinates described in latitude/longitude. I have found one formulation of this calculation as

[image]

Note, I tried formatting the equation with LaTeX but I couldn't see how to do that on stack, using $$ didn't seem to do anything.

This calculation can be found on various sites like link [1](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/) [2](http://www.anycalculator.com/longitude.htm) [3](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) but I have not been able to find a derivation or a source for the calculation.

I am looking for a derivation or an explanation of the derivation of this calculation.

Comment: Book recommendation are often offtopic, and GIS sister site may be more relevant (but still offtopic). You can get some docs in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Further_reading . Now I do not find the relavant book (online), but this is just geometry, so basic geodesy book should derive the formulae for you.

Comment: Sorry I may have formulated this poorly, the book was just a means to an end. In reality I am looking for the derivation or an explanation of the derivation. I didn't know there was a GIS sister site but thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I understood correctly, usually you books should derive the formula, and explain the derivations: it helps understanding the use and the meaning. Else there is also a mathematical sister site (icon top right: you get all sister site): your question could be just about ellipsis. Just that mathematics uses a different convention on angle, so you should translate them